WooCommerce and Ship Station Custom Field
I'm trying to export the shipping class of a product to Custom Field 2 in ShipStation here's what I tried..
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipstation_export_custom_field_2', 'shipstation_custom_field_2' );
function shipstation_custom_field_2() {
    // Get the current product object
    global $product;

    // If the product object is not available or shipping class is empty, return an empty string
    if ( ! $product || empty( $product->get_shipping_class() ) ) {
        return '';
    }

    // Return the shipping class of the product
    return $product->get_shipping_class();
}


